# React Native list of required items for ios/android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Please be experienced with react native So I was wanting to get involved creating my app. I do want it to be on android and ios. So maybe two different list and everything I need to get setup for it. I already have node.js and react-create-my-app installed, I know I will probably need the android sdk and ios dev tools or something, but if someone has all the specific items I will need before starting and also any tips about say building the android version then just changing files and dependencies a, b and c to cross-platform the app. Anything like that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Basically you need Android Studio and if you are going to build for iOS as well, need a mac with xcode. Then you can setup your environment with following guide and run react native app without any problem. Also there is no clear package list to mention because it depends entirely on your project and how you are going to achieve your goal. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Okay. But, what I am confused about, is you eject your project, e.g. npm run eject to work on it in android studio (I am on windows), so would I just write my project in react native. Then eject it, or would I start the project by ejecting it. If so, what is the point in writing it in react native in the first place. Or what is compatible between the two. What can I write that works for android and ios and what would I have to change for it to work on each platform. And I can just virtualize mac os for the ios right? Sorry, I am just learning react so I am full of questions right now lol

Comment: Ejecting uses to eject your expo app to Native code. It's only necessary if you use expo to build your code. If you didn't use it, there is no need of ejecting.